# Relationship between subsemigroups of GL2 and SL2

Tags: matrices, group-theory, semigroups

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $X$ be the semigroup generated by elements of form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0&1\\1&a
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a\in A$

Let $Y$ be the semigroup generated by all products of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0&1\\1&a
\end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}
    0&1\\1&b
\end{pmatrix} $$
where $a,b \in A$.

Clearly $X\subseteq \mbox{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and $Y \subseteq \mbox{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) $.

How can one show also that $Y = X \cap  \mbox{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})  $ ?

It is clear to me that $Y \subseteq X \cap  \mbox{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ but I do not know how to go about showing the reverse direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element in $X$ is a product of matrices  $A=\prod_{i=0}^nA_i=\prod_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & a_i 
\end{pmatrix}$. In order for this to have determinant $1$, you need $n$ to be even. Therefore you can write $A=(A_1A_2)(A_3A_4)...(A_{n-1}A_n)$.

Comment: Thank you. That was really easily explained.